# Run a jar file with parameters several times

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have jar file that receives 4 parameters for running.

I am able to execute the file using below:

> java -jar example.jar par1 par2 par2 par4.

I have to execute this program several times and I have to change the parameters in every execution. At the moment I am doing it manually and it is working but time consuming.

Is there any way to do it automatically?

Update:
I am working on Ubuntu 15.10. And the parameters change depending on the dataset of the input. But I have those parameters in a txt file.
I am starting with java so I think I am going to read about the .bat to see how to create one.

Update 2: Regarding the file with the parameters that I have to change in every time that I execute the program cotains this information:
For example:

350 2 4 test1.txt //Parameters for execution 1
350 5 7 test1.txt //Parameters for execution 2
400 3 5 test2.txt //Parameters for execution 3 
...

So the numbers are the parameters that I need as an input for my algorithm and the file stores the dataset that contains the information to analyze. How can I crate this .bat file, to avoid doing manually my executions.

Comment: On what base do those parameters change ?

Comment: Write a .bat or .sh script

Comment: which OS? You can create a script specific to that OS.

Comment: According to your update you should write a batch or powershell script. It would have to read from the text file and call the java executable. Maybe if you describe your text file and the way its content has to be mapped to the java call you'll be able to get an exhaustive solution.

Comment: Simple way: Write a script.
Do it via Java, batch , powersheel, python, perl, etc is your option